# Check if an image contains another image

Tags: image, comparison, png, screenshot, awtrobot

Im trying to check if a screenshot contains an image that is saved in the project resources, I need to find a 100% match only and would like to not use any extra libraries, now with that being said, I have no idea how to do so.

heres a few questions:,

1. do I compare the two buffered images together? do I change them into something else?
2. Il have to compare it atleast once a second or so. (just as general information)
3. I have a resource folder under my project in eclipse and the .png files are shown as text, is there a way to change that? I tried tinkering with the settings, no luck yet.

   public static BufferedImage screenshot(){
       BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenSize);
       return capture;
   }

this is my screenshot, another bufferedimage is for example "compare", where the size of the compared image is smaller than the screenshot. how will I be able to check if the image contain the second image?

*For those who wondering, im trying to make a simple program that clicks a certain image once it pops up.